# Restrain vs curb

Tags: word-choice, differences, meaning-in-context

In an exam I found this phrase:

> There was very strong support for the police who were determined to **curb** this kind of crime.

There was a choice between *restrain* and *curb*. Why was *curb* the right word?

Comment: What does the dictionary say about *restrain* and *curb*?

Answer (score 2):

To me, *restraining* more strongly implies *pulling back* or otherwise impeding forward progress.

But *curbing* is more about setting the limits within which something is confined.

The two words are often pretty much interchangeable (they're very similar metaphors), but in OP's case I would definitely use *curb* because "this kind of crime" isn't something I can easily imagine being held back from rampaging down the street. But I *can* imagine antisocial behaviour spreading around like blocked drainwater wherever it's unchecked by police curbs.

Answer (score 1):

The two words are similar but slightly different in meaning. Restrain tends to be more physical-- for example, if you're physically holding someone's arms behind their back you're restraining them. 'Curb' on the other hand functions more like 'reduce', 'decrease', 'discourage'... and it can apply to intangible things, unlike 'restrain'.

An example: Curb your instincts vs. restrain yourself. Your instincts cannot be restrained because they aren't physical; your body, however, can be. 'Curb yourself' doesn't make any sense, and neither does 'restrain your instincts'.

Upon looking the words up, there are example where the two words are used interchangeably. Google gets me "the need to restrain public expenditure", for example, where I would personally use 'curb'.

Another note is that 'curb' seems to be more appropriate in cases of self-restraint, while 'restrain' feels more like a limitation forced by a separate entity.

Comment: ...I realize that I could be wrong, but I'd like to know how.

Answer (score 0):

A curb is a systemic as opposed to active restraint. A classic illustration is the curb and gutter along the road: the gutter caries water, the curb blocks and directs the flow. In your example rather than stopping each crime, you change the environment to make the crime more difficult/dangerous/obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrain people from committing crimes; but you can't 'restrain' crime itself except, indirectly, by restraining people. Here, curb refers to the incidence of crime: the police want it to lessen. 'Curtail' would also work, and is probably more apt.